# Session variable loses index after refresh in Yii

Tags: php, session, yii

I'm having a problem with the session variables in my web app.
The thing is that I set it with the following code and check if it exists and only if not then I update it.

The idea is to know if the user is enterprise or not for his session.

I use the following code:

```
        $logo_class = "logo";

        if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
            define("ENT_LIM_PROD_COUNT", 10000);

            $user_id = Stores::model()->findByPk(Products::model()->getStoreID())->user_id;

            if(array_key_exists('is_enterprise', Yii::app()->session)) {
                if(Yii::app()->session['is_enterprise'] === true)
                    $logo_class = "logo_ent";
            } else {
                $total_prod = LicenseMngr::getFeatureAllocTotal($user_id, LicenseMngr::FEATURE_PRODUCTS);
                Yii::app()->session['is_enterprise'] = ($total_prod > ENT_LIM_PROD_COUNT ? true : false);

                if(Yii::app()->session['is_enterprise'] === true)
                    $logo_class = "logo_ent";
            }
        }
```

I have tried using different types of sessions in my config file and now it's:

```
        'session'=>array(
            'autoStart' => true,
            'sessionName' => 'session',
            'timeout' => 30758400
        ),
```

Now, the problem is that every time I refresh the page the index "is_enterprise" is not in the session array as if it was never set.

I have tried changing the session save directory to /var/tmp.

I'm running:

```
Darwin niflheim 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

PHP Version 5.4.15 (web)
```

The following line does a rest call to a server to get information we need (It's probably the only thing that isn't related to YII here):

```
$total_prod = LicenseMngr::getFeatureAllocTotal($user_id, LicenseMngr::FEATURE_PRODUCTS);
```

P.S: This is not the only custom variable that it happens with, I hope that helps.

Comment: You might want to use setState, so the information is saved in the session data called States.

Comment: OK, now it's better but the thing is that it doesn't save the value on the first time only after I refresh the page once. I replaced all the session calls with Yii::app()->user->getState("is_enterprise", false) and Yii::app()->user->setState("is_enterprise", true|false as needed)

Comment: You don't need to use getState, just Yii::app()->user->stateID, it uses magic getter and setters, if you use is_enterprise = something, it will change the value, otherway it will return the value that holds.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/, btw this information should be set a login time, to know if the user is enterprise or not. You can also use RBAC.

Comment: What I'm wondering is does using state ID's makes it persistent between page redirects and refreshes? Our goal is to set it once and use it through the entire session so we won't need to use the rest call which is pretty slow sometimes on each refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So after a while we were able to solve the problem... Apparently the session variable in YII is not an array but an object and you can access it as an array so array_key_exists didn't work.

Changing it to isset solved the problem.